# I want to replace the back light enclosure of my Honda Accord, how difficult would that be?

Tags: honda, replace, accord, tail-lights

I have a 2000 Honda Accord. The back right lamp enclosure is cracked. Moisture gets in there sometimes and I have to replace the bulbs from time to time. I'm sure it'll be more cost efficient to replace it myself but I've never done anything like this. How would I go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the trunk near the taillight you will find some plastic screws that hold the carpet in place. Using a flat head screwdriver remove them by unscrewing them or prying them out. Moving the carpet should reveal the mounting bolts for the taillight. It will most likely require a 10mm deep socket to remove the nuts. Disconnect the lamp sockets from the light assembly. Reverse the process to install the new lamp. As a note you do not need to go to the dealer for this part. The least expensive may be a used assembly from a junkyard or auto recycle center,  most likely available in a day or two. More expensive but still less than the dealer is your local auto parts store, it will most likely need to be ordered and take a few days to arrive.